# Mapping financial data with commas in Python

Tags: python, excel

How can I map PnL-label to each line in the first table using such 'united' construction from the second table? (I can only imagine how to 'unzip' these united structure in the second table but it make the-rules-table too long and non-all-purpose for some reasons. I guess there is some tricky decision via 'isin' or some kind of that but I'm very week at the moment in syntax + the idea to create a very long 'not-united' table gripped my mind...(because it works with 'merge')

```
ActivityCode    CodeDepartment  BranchCode  Account Special Code    Value
P   PR  M12 501102083   NaN 1000
P   PR  M11 501102083   NaN 2000
P   PR  M13 637102089   NaN 3000
P   TR  EGS 621102088   NaN 200
P   PC  O11 541202084   NaN 500
P   PR  M72 472002082   ZS  130
```

[image: 1]

---

```
Account BranchCode  ActivityCode    CodeDepartment  PnL
0   465002082   NaN P   PN  Hub Fixed
1   465002082   M11 P   PN  Depot Fixed
2   465002082   NaN P   TR  Hub Variable
3   542302084   NaN A   AC  Overheads
4   542302084   NaN A   AL  Overheads
5   542302084   NaN A   BL  Overheads
6   542302084   NaN A   FS  Overheads
7   542302084   NaN A   HR  Overheads
8   542302084   NaN A   IT  Overheads
9   542302084   NaN A   LW  Overheads
10  542302084   NaN P   IT  Hub Fixed
11  542302084   NaN P   PR  Hub Fixed
12  542302084   NaN P   TR  Hub Variable
13  542302084   NaN S   CM  Sales
14  542302084   NaN S   CS  Sales
15  542302084   NaN S   MR  Sales
16  543402084   NaN A   GD  Overheads
```

[image: 2]

---

I expect:

[image: 3]

Comment: Your inputs does not match the given images. Can you *double-check* ? Also, see [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.